# Bootstrap Modal can not open .hidden --> .show when it wasn't already open

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

**Situation:** Two modals (modal1 and modal2. The modal1should open the modal 2 after the modal1 is closed.

1. Open Modal1
2. Click button to close Modal1 and open Modal2

The javascript code:

> ```
>               $("#btToOpenModal2").click(function() {
>                   $('#modal1').modal('hide');
>
>                   setTimeout(function(){ $('#modal2').modal('show'); }, 1000);
>
>               });
> ```

**Problem:**
The new modal just show the grey background.

If I did open first the modal2 with a button (and close) and then I use the javascript code (other button), then its work.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open Modal</button>
```

I do not really understand why that isn't work, maybe someone had already this problem.

Comment: Please share all the html and javascript not only some snippets, so we could help.

Comment: @caisah I create a simple one...

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this..

```
$('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
});
```

hidden.bs.modal is fired when modal1 is closed after completion of transition
or it you want to fire it immediately as it is closed use the following:

```
$('#modal1').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
});
```

Comment: The problem is that when the panel is closed (modal code is there) then is not working =)

Answer (score 1):

I create a easy example without something else. Now the Modal1(id)->Button->open2(id) do not open anymore the Modal2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal2</button>

  <!-- Modal2 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal1 -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="open2">Open Modal</button>
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#open2").click(function() {

    $('#myModal1').modal('hide');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#mymodal2').modal('show');
    }, 1000);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```